# Can I create a Logstash pipeline which takes both Apache web logs and queries from a Mysql database (based on the logs) as input?

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, logstash

I have Apache web logs with one of the fields as SessionIDs. The correspomding username for the SessionIDS is kept in the database. I need to create a Logstash pipeline which takes the web logs, and also adds the Username (kept in Mysql database) corresponding to the SessionID for each log. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the logs as an input for the pipeline, and the MySQL database as an enrichment stage for those logs.

You can read the jdbc_static example here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/lookup-enrichment.html